# Getting duplicate values while comparing with the map

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

Initially i will be selecting a list of student names in a page and submit for getting the address details.StudentNames will be stored in the studentDetailMapList.While looping through the list , i will compare the student names with the AddressDetailsMap to retrieve the addressDetails.But when there are students with same names , the first iteration returns the exact address but when the second iteration happens , it again returns the 1st student address instead of the second student address.It is getting the duplicate values

```
for (i=studentDetailMapList.values().iterator;i.hasNext();)
{
  detailMap = (Map)i.Next();
  sDetails =  (StudentDetails)detailMap.get("Student");
  student = sDetails.getRollNo();
  StudentAddressDetails studentAddressDetails  = getDetailswithAddress(AddressDetailsMap,sDetails);
}

private StudentAddressDetails getDetailswithAddress(Map AddressDetailsMap,sDetails student)
{
      StudentAddressDetails addDetails = null;
        try{
        for(Iterator itr = AddressDetailsMap.values().iterator();itr.hasNext();){
                addDetails = (StudentAddressDetails )itr.next();
                if( (addDetails != null) && (addDetails.getStudentID().equals(student.getId()))){
                    return addDetails;
                }
        }
        }catch(Throwable t){
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid the duplicate while comparing with the map?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are using the the map data structure wrong.

A map is an object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

You can not have multiple addresses for the same name, you should use other property for the map, maybe a Student ID, even the list's index should work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.AddressDetailsMap is already mapped.AddressDetailsMap (Detail.sRollNo ,addressDetails).And one more thing only the selection is by student names , but it is compared only with the student roll no. My requirement allows student names to be same.

Comment: Use `AddressDetailsMap.get(student.getStudentID())` instead of iterating over the map to find your student.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a UUID in your student's class and work with it for managing their data

**EDIT for response**

[Java's UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) give you the basic Java's UUID.

you can manage [your own sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)  - This way may be helpfull for indexing Students in database with UNIQUE_ID.

The best thing to manage  your IDs : use a `HashMap<Integer,Student>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.UUID? Could u please share with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Each key of your `AddressDetailsMap` map must be an identifier (studentId) and not the student name.

EDIT:
In this case, your method should look like this:

```
private StudentAddressDetails getDetailswithAddress(Map AddressDetailsMap,sDetails student) {
          return AddressDetailsMap.get(student.getStudentID());
}
```